# pandas returning the values from a column with zero standard deviation of another column transaction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am relatively new to pandas.I am trying to return the rows or customer ID's which either have standard deviation of "0" in units column or the time difference between each subsequent transaction is less than 10 minutes. for example in data below transaction 1,4,5 is 50 units andstandard deviation will be '0', likewise transaction 3 and 6 has time difference of 1 sec, and 6&7 has difference of 3 seconds, so rows 1,4,5,3,6,7 should be returned.kindly help me with that I am stucked.the data is shown in the table:

```
index|  customerid|  code |   transactionID|  units |  tstamp
1 |968794 |200 |46408 |  50 | 2019.06.28 00:03:22
2 |874213 |201 |6526  |  25 | 2019.06.28 00:03:20
3 |226292 |202 |18609 |  55 | 2019.06.28 00:03:22
4 |968794 |203 |50466 |  50 | 2019.06.28 00:03:26
5 |968794 |204 |65687 |  50 | 2019.06.28 00:03:33
6 |226292 |205 |232   |  23 | 2019.06.28 00:03:23
7 |226292 |206 |1232  |  45 | 2019.06.28 00:03:26
8 |874213 |207 |3343  |  32 | 2019.06.28 00:23:45
9 |874213 |208 |2343  |  54 | 2019.06.28 00:45:55
```

i have tried this code, but do not know where to go further.for my case here , the code should return me rows with  customer ID 8968794 and 8226292. here is what I have tried but do not know how even start with time part.

```
df1= df.loc[(df['units'].groupby(df['customerid']).std()==0)]
```

this gives me the error:
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

After Mr Suraj answer, I have tried to use the code

```
df['TimeDiff'] = df.groupby('customerid')['tstamp'].transform(lambda g: (g.max()-g.min()).seconds)
df2 = df[df['TimeDiff']<600]
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

df3 comes to be:

```
 |TimeDiff  | code  |  customerid  |index |  tid| tstamp | units
0   NaN |200| 8968794| 1 |  46408 |  2019-06-28 00:03:22 50
3   NaN |203| 8968794| 4 |  50466 |  2019-06-28 00:03:26 50
4   NaN |204| 8968794| 5 |  65687 |  2019-06-28 00:03:33 50
0   11.0|200| 8968794| 1 |  46408 |  2019-06-28 00:03:22 50
2   4.0 |202| 8226292| 3 |  18609 |  2019-06-28 00:03:22 55
3   11.0|203| 8968794| 4 |  50466 |  2019-06-28 00:03:26 50
4   11.0|204| 8968794| 5 |  65687 |  2019-06-28 00:03:33 50
5   4.0 |205| 8226292| 6 |  232   |  2019-06-28 00:03:23 23
6   4.0 |206| 8226292| 7 |  1232  |  2019-06-28 00:03:26 45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you groupby and do std directly, the result is only the size of the unique customerid(since that's the groupby metric) and loc gives the error. What you need is transform function which does it for each corresponding row.

```
df1= df.loc[(df['units'].groupby(df['customerid']).transform('std')==0)]
```

For second part of question, to get customer id where transaction difference is less than 10min,

```
df['TimeDiff'] = df.groupby('customerid')['tstamp'].transform(lambda g: (g.max()-g.min()).seconds)
df2 = df[df['TimeDiff']<600]
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

df3 should be your desired result

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Suraj Motaparthy, this is great tweak. However this solved first part of the problem. the second part is that time difference between each transaction is less than 10 minutes for each customer, I would be grateful if you can give me this hint as well

Comment: @Shaukathussain Updated answer. If this is what you are looking for, mark the answer as the right one

Comment: thank you Mr Suraj, but when I run it , I get an error **:   unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'**

Comment: @Shaukathussain It seems your tstamp column type is str. Change it to timestamp by : ```df['tstamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['tstamp'])```

Comment: i have added the resultant dataframe, which have some not understandable result. Kindly check it

Comment: @Shaukathussain That's expected. I assumed you will be dropping off TimeDiff column as you won't need it. ```df3.drop(labels=['TimeDiff'], axis=1, inplace=True)```

Comment: sorry to make comments long, but why the code returned 9 rows instead 6 rows

Comment: @Shaukathussain Can you do the drop statement on df2 and run it before the concat statement. That should fix the duplicates.